# Some gists on github have very many forks. How can I find the most recently active and/or heavily modified?

Tags: python, git, pandas, github, gist

For example, there is this very popular gist on tmux shortcuts with very many forks:

[tmux shortcuts & cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/MohamedAlaa/2961058)

This particular gist has [2156 forks](https://gist.github.com/MohamedAlaa/2961058/forks) at present, so others may have added many other useful additions in their individual forks that never got merged in. Looking manually through all 2156 of them for useful tidbits would be a very arduous process.

Is there a way to see which of them (in order of importance, but partial answers are OK, too):

1. Have the most lines added?
2. Have been updated recently?

..., in some sort of automated fashion, so that I don't have to click on each fork and see how it differs to find the "diamonds in the rough?"

Comment: You should be able to automate this by using API and browsing commits in forks: https://api.github.com/gists/2961058/forks https://api.github.com/gists/4595125/commits

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick python script based on [rob006](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258835/some-gists-on-github-have-very-many-forks-how-can-i-find-the-most-recently-acti#comment87618340_50258835)'s suggestion. The idea is to go over the list of forks and then for each `commit_url`, get the `committed_at` key and print the result sorted by the same.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'

df = pd.read_json('https://api.github.com/gists/2961058/forks')

df['updated'] = None
for i,j in df.iterrows():
  sub_df = pd.read_json(j['commits_url'])
  df['updated'].loc[i] = sub_df['committed_at'][0]    

print(df[['html_url', 'updated']].sort_values(by='updated', ascending=False).to_string())
```

Output:

```
               html_url              updated
5   https://gist.github.com/4739242  2016-12-06 14:31:32
13  https://gist.github.com/5277937  2013-04-03 20:18:26
8   https://gist.github.com/4770160  2013-02-12 14:24:52
0   https://gist.github.com/4472784  2013-01-08 09:14:47
17  https://gist.github.com/5321628  2012-10-03 15:38:50
28  https://gist.github.com/5462736  2012-10-03 15:38:50
27  https://gist.github.com/5450432  2012-10-03 15:38:50
26  https://gist.github.com/5408497  2012-10-03 15:38:50
25  https://gist.github.com/5394420  2012-10-03 15:38:50
24  https://gist.github.com/5386007  2012-10-03 15:38:50
23  https://gist.github.com/5380517  2012-10-03 15:38:50
22  https://gist.github.com/5358216  2012-10-03 15:38:50
21  https://gist.github.com/5355396  2012-10-03 15:38:50
20  https://gist.github.com/5347298  2012-10-03 15:38:50
19  https://gist.github.com/5340495  2012-10-03 15:38:50
18  https://gist.github.com/5338594  2012-10-03 15:38:50
15  https://gist.github.com/5311472  2012-10-03 15:38:50
16  https://gist.github.com/5317428  2012-10-03 15:38:50
1   https://gist.github.com/4595125  2012-10-03 15:38:50
14  https://gist.github.com/5304285  2012-10-03 15:38:50
12  https://gist.github.com/5195021  2012-10-03 15:38:50
11  https://gist.github.com/5143245  2012-10-03 15:38:50
10  https://gist.github.com/4997403  2012-10-03 15:38:50
9   https://gist.github.com/4772114  2012-10-03 15:38:50
7   https://gist.github.com/4753544  2012-10-03 15:38:50
6   https://gist.github.com/4739782  2012-10-03 15:38:50
4   https://gist.github.com/4694620  2012-10-03 15:38:50
3   https://gist.github.com/4659865  2012-10-03 15:38:50
2   https://gist.github.com/4654117  2012-10-03 15:38:50
29  https://gist.github.com/5467292  2012-10-03 15:38:50
```

From the results, it looks like [https://gist.github.com/4739242](https://gist.github.com/d-g-h/4739242) is the most recently updated fork.

Note: Wait for some time before running the script again. GitHub may [limit](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting) your access and you'll get 403 error like below:

```
{
  "message": "API rate limit exceeded for 116.73.235.229. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting"
}
```

> For unauthenticated requests, the rate limit allows for up to 60
>   requests per hour. Unauthenticated requests are associated with the
>   originating IP address, and not the user making requests.

TODO:

- Add authentication to avoid rate limiting
- Compare forked version with the original (word count?) to avoid gists which have made no improvement to the original

Answer (score 0):

I created a similar python script to [@Chankey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257635/chankey-pathak) above but mine does repos and not gists and shows a little bit more info (shows ahead and behind commits as well). I wanted to know the same as OP for any fork because some repos can just get out of hand with the number of forks and forks of forks (Can github do anything with that to show the user better information?). Let me know what everyone thinks of the script - I'm definitely open to suggestions. It was something I threw together: https://github.com/ikwyl6/git-diff-forks